# Runtime-error in wpf with Window.AllowsTransparent set to true

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I get an exception thrown at runtime when I set `AllowsTransparency="True"` I get an exception saying the `WindowStyle` can not be set to `None` if `AllowsTransparency` is set to true. Even if I explicitly say that `WindowStyle` is set to `SingleBorder` I get this error. However, if I set `WindowStyle` to `SingleBorder` and remove the `AllowsTransparency`-tag, I get no error, and the top of the window (the icon, name and close, minimize and maximize-buttons) disappears. Anyone knows what can cause this? Or is it just a bug in .Net 4.0 rc?

[Edit]
I've tried this in VS2008 too, and I get the same results. What I wan't to achieve is a simple window where I draw the window myself and leave nothing up to the system, however, things like minimizing and maximizing must still work.

Comment: I just threw a quick window together, and this worked fine.  Can you post your Window's XAML so we can figure out what you may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error should be the opposite so you're either running into a bug or mis-reading the error message. Any time you have AllowsTransparency="True" the only valid WindowStyle value is None. Any of the others add OS dependent window chrome which can't be forced to have transparency in its client area.